# the code is not returning any value and the code is being stored in user defined function instead of stored procedure

Tags: eclipse, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bank( 
in  bk_cd_in          CHAR( 4 ) , 
out bk_cd_out         CHAR( 4 ) ,
out bk_nm             CHAR( 40 ) ,
out brh_cd            CHAR( 8 ) ,
out bak_hnm           CHAR( 40 ) ,
out ur_cd             CHAR(18),
out updt              DATE, 
out updt_flag         CHAR( 1 ) ,
out brh_nm            CHAR( 40 ) , 
out cty_nm            CHAR( 40 ) )
SELECT bank_cd, bank_nm, branch_cd, bank_hnm, user_cd, update_dt, update_flag, branch_nm, city_nm
FROM bankmst
WHERE bank_cd = bk_cd_in
into bk_cd_out, bk_nm, brh_cd, bak_hnm, ur_cd, updt, updt_flag, brh_nm, cty_nm ;
```

the calling code written in jsp the out parametres are empty and on running the jsp page the error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: ***Unknown column 'b1' in 'field list' ended***

```
try
{
    cs = con.prepareCall("{call bank(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
    String s1 = para;
    cs.setString(1,para);
    cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.CHAR);    
    cs.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    cs.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(9, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(10, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(11, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    rs = cs.executeQuery();
    out.println("\nexecuted 3\n");
    String b1 = cs.getString(2);
    String b2 = cs.getString(3);
    String b3 = cs.getString(4);
    String b4 = cs.getString(5);
    String b5 = cs.getString(6);    
    java.util.Date b6 = cs.getDate(7);
    String b7 = cs.getString(8);
    String b8 = cs.getString(9);
    String b9 = cs.getString(10);
    System.out.println(b1);
    System.out.println(b2);
    System.out.println(b3);
    System.out.println(b4);
    System.out.println(b5);
    System.out.println(b6);
    System.out.println(b7);
    System.out.println(b8);
    System.out.println(b9);
}
```

..I am using eclipse 3.6 and the code is written in mysql 5.1

Comment: Show relevant code that calls your stored procedure. IMHO it should be much easier to return a resultset instead of using a bunch of out parameters.

Comment: the jsp file is added pls check